# CVS: How to re-add a file as normal type when it was initially added as binary

Tags: cvs, wincvs

I have a small problem that would seem to be easy to solve, but I am having trouble doing so. Using CVS/WinCVS, a file was added as binary that should not have been added. I want to correct this and add it as a normal type, but whenever I remove the existing file through WinCVS, and try to re-add using the Add command, it adds it back in as binary.

I was told by another developer that if I intend to add it back in with the same name, I am out of luck. Unfortunately I can't simply add the same file with a new name, as this is a .resx file generated by Visual Studio for C# internationalization.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the difference between binary and text files, as far as CVS is concerned, is keyword subsitution; you can see this by running `cvs log -h` and looking for the "`keyword substitution:`" line.  You should be able to use `cvs admin` to change it, probably something like `cvs admin -kv filename`.  (This applies to the command-line tool; I haven't used `WinCVS`.)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use cvs update -kkv and then force commit my file in order to achieve my results.